How to vertically align unnumbered chapters consistently with numbered chapters?
I am working on a LaTeX document where all chapters have the "Chapter N" heading removed, leaving only the chapter name:
% Remove "Chapter N"
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}

Additionally, I make some chapters appear in the table of contents unnumbered. This is how I achieve this:
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Third Chapter (this one is unnumbered)}
\chapter*{Third Chapter (this one is unnumbered)}
% Content of third chapter

However, I notice that for unnumbered chapters the vertical spacing from the top of the page to the chapter name is shorter compared to the spacing for numbered chapters:

Here’s a minimal working example to illustrate the issue:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[
    bookmarks,
    colorlinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    pdftitle={},
    pdfauthor={},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfkeywords={}
]{hyperref}

% -----------------------------------------

% Remove "Chapter N"
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}

% Adjust alignment
\titlespacing\chapter{0pt}{-150pt}{20pt}

% -----------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
% Content of first chapter

\chapter{Second Chapter}
% Content of second chapter

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Third Chapter (this one is unnumbered)}
\chapter*{Third Chapter (this one is unnumbered)}
% Content of third chapter

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References (this one is unnumbered)}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
% Content of references

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

In this example, the spacing before Contents, Third Chapter and Bibliography is not consistent with the spacing before the First and Second Chapters. How can I universally resolve this inconsistency?

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

@JoséCarlosSantos ...I did? Please let me know if it doesn't work for you

Remove the empty line.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[
    bookmarks,
    colorlinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    pdftitle={},
    pdfauthor={},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfkeywords={}
]{hyperref}

% -----------------------------------------

% Remove "Chapter N"
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}{0pt}{}

% Adjust alignment
\titlespacing\chapter{0pt}{-140pt}{20pt}

% -----------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
% Content of first chapter

\chapter{Second Chapter}
% Content of second chapter

\chapter*{Third Chapter (this one is unnumbered)}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Third Chapter (this one is unnumbered)}
% Content of third chapter

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
% Content of references
\bibitem{a} Something

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


Note that \addcontentsline adds an anchor point itself, so \phantomsection isn't needed. Anyway, you need \clearpage if you want \addcontentsline before \chapter*.
For the bibliography, just load tocbibind.

Thank you! I had assumed that removing the empty line would be the solution but wasn’t sure how to do it. Marking as correct solution.

This is very easy using a more configurable class like scrreprt instead of report:
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,sfdefaults=false,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[
    bookmarks,
    colorlinks=false,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    pdftitle={},
    pdfauthor={},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfkeywords={}
]{hyperref}

% -----------------------------------------

% Remove chapter number
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}
% Optional remove chapter number in running head
%\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}

% Adjust alignment
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  afterindent=false,% to make negative beforeskip possible
  beforeskip=-140pt,% move the heading to the top edge of the page
  afterskip=20pt,% vertical distance after the heading
]{chapter}

% -----------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
% Content of first chapter

\chapter{Second Chapter}
% Content of second chapter

\addchap{Third Chapter (this one is unnumbered)}% with ToC entry
% Content of third chapter

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
% Content of references
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


As you can see, you don't need an external package for this. And you don't need to handle with \addcontentsline for not numbered chapters with ToC entry, because the class already provides a new command for this. The ToC entry for the bibliography is also done automatically using class option bibliography=totoc. The other options are only for lookalike the formatting of report. If you also want to change the font of the heading see option font in the description of \RedeclareSectionCommand in one of the KOMA-Script user manuals.
